# Running spark streaming program on cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-computing, spark-streaming

I have implemented a scala program to find the most popular hashtags on twitter using spark streaming. I have implemented it on eclipse scala IDE. I have access to a cluster called comet, operated by SDSC. I want to run my scala program on this cluster.

Please guide me through the steps to do the above as I have very limited idea about linux.

Below is the code

```
object PopularHashtags {


  def setupLogging() = {
    import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}   
    val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
    rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)   
  }

  def setupTwitter() = {
    import scala.io.Source

    for (line <- Source.fromFile("../twitter.txt").getLines) {
      val fields = line.split(" ")
      if (fields.length == 2) {
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth." + fields(0), fields(1))
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    setupTwitter()

    val ssc = new StreamingContext("local[*]", "PopularHashtags", Seconds(1))

    setupLogging()

    val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)

    val statuses = tweets.map(status => status.getText())

    val tweetwords = statuses.flatMap(tweetText => tweetText.split(" "))

    val hashtags = tweetwords.filter(word => word.startsWith("#"))

    val hashtagKeyValues = hashtags.map(hashtag => (hashtag, 1))

    val hashtagCounts = hashtagKeyValues.reduceByKeyAndWindow( (x,y) => x + y, (x,y) => x - y, Seconds(300), Seconds(1))

    val sortedResults = hashtagCounts.transform(rdd => rdd.sortBy(x => x._2, false))

    sortedResults.print

    ssc.checkpoint("C:/checkpoint/")
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }  
}
```

P.S.: The twitter API keys are stored in a text file in my eclipse workspace.